# get records from database of all days of given month and year and blank if not available in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get records from employee attendance table. I want to get all date record of given month and year. If no records available for the day then it will display only date and other fields will blank. Table given below :

```
Table: emp_attendance

id   emp_id   attendance_date    attendance   reason
1    1        2014-08-01         P
2    1        2014-08-02         A           seek
.
.
.
26   1        2014-08-26         P
```

In the given table suppose there is no record for some specific dates for example, 2014-08-27, 2014-08-28, 2014-08-29,2014-08-30,2014-08-31.

So How can I get records of August 2014 like below result.

```
Expected Result Would Be:

date               id       emp_id    attendance   reason
2014-08-01         1        1         P
2014-08-02         2        1         A            seek
.
.
.
2014-08-26         26       1         P
2014-08-27         NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
2014-08-28         NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
2014-08-29         NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
2014-08-30         NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
2014-08-31         NULL     NULL      NULL         NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a table that has all the days of the month in it. Then you can do

```
SELECT d.date, a.*
FROM dates AS d -- This is the table with all days
LEFT JOIN emp_attendance AS a ON d.date = a.attendance_date
ORDER BY d.date
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e1bb3/1)

If your `dates` table just contains the day numbers, not full dates, you can do:

```
SELECT d.date, a.*
FROM dates AS d -- This is the table with all days
LEFT JOIN emp_attendance AS a ON d.date = DAY(a.attendance_date)
    AND YEAR(a.attendance_date) = 2014 AND MONTH(a.attendance_date) = 8
ORDER BY d.date
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80a42/3)

Comment: It prints null for all the dates

Comment: What is the datatype of the `attendance_date` field?

Comment: It should work. Can you make a sqlfiddle showing what you tried?

Comment: Where is the `dates` table?

Comment: I did it myself, see my fiddle.

Comment: Yes your demo is working but what might be the problem with my db?

Comment: How should I know? I can't see what you did.

Comment: I did it on fiddle. I got where is the problem, you entered full dates in dates table where I stored only days (0-31).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the other tests on `a` also have to be in the `ON` clause for `LEFT JOIN` to work correctly. See the update

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

SELECT * FROM emp_attendance WHERE 
YEAR(attendance_date)='2014' and MONTH(attendance_date)='8' 
ORDER BY attendance_date

if you need to add one more condition then you can also add ( AND attendance is null AND reason is null)

Comment: This won't show dates that don't exist in the `emp_attendance` table.

Comment: This will print records that has given year and month and not the dates that are not in the database for the given month and year. see expected result.